# Movie making from lyrics with timestamps in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyffmpeg, musixmatch

I have lyrics from musixmatch with timestamps. I want to form video with the lyric lines in the video along with images in a file numbered from 1-n.

As seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357463/creating-a-sequence-of-images-from-lyrics-to-use-in-ffmpeg) post, I thought ffmpeg would be something which can help me but there aren't much information that i can find.

Also the answer given by @llogan, gives very vague idea of forming videos with "subtitle filter" in ffmpeg.

It would be very helpful you can provide an example to explain your idea.(It can also help other coders at any time :) )

Thanks in advance

Comment: All you need to do is convert your lyrics to SRT format, like the example in the answer you linked to. `ffmpeg` can do the rest easily.

Comment: What @llogan means is that you have to convert your lyrics with timestamps to an external subtitle file first. The example you linked uses an SRT file, which would be fairly easy to generate.
This would be easiest if you could post a few example lines of the lyrics with the timestamps. I also can't tell if you want the lyrics "hardsubbed" (added as part of the image) or "softsubbed" (so you can toggle them on/off). If you can add that information, I can give you a complete answer.